# How to enable strict mode for a single file in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am cleaning up a project that did have set `strict` mode to false. I am on the way to clean up the project but rather than turning this option on in `tsconfig.json` I would like to go from file to file.

Is there a way to enable strict mode only for certain files?

Comment: If your files are interconnected (as most projects are) I wouldn't be surprised if this is impossible.

Comment: I think you can do this by using individual `tsconfig.json` for your desired directory and extending the outer `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @h-sifat I will look into this, thank you!

Comment: @HelloWorld See the documentation of the `tsconfig.json` on the official typescript website [tsconfig.json docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig).